# Stop images on sd card from showing up in gallery?

Tags: android

I keep some png files on the user's sd card. Some users report that these images are showing up in their gallery application. Sounds like the gallery implementation on some devices search out any image files they can find on the sd card and show it in the gallery. Is there a way to tell the system not to include these images in the gallery? It's just an annoyance to the users.

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can hide individual files from the gallery with a `.` prefix.  For example `.myimage.png`

I'm not sure what version dependencies the above has and it doesn`t work with some third-party picture tools like the Gallery.

You should add a file named `.nomedia` into the directory where your images are.  You may need to eject and re-insert the SD card before the images disappear from gallery (or otherwise trigger the media scanner) after creating this file on a phone that the Gallery has already picked up the files in the Gallery.

I think the `.nomedia` option is the best solution, although again, third party tools may not respect the `.nomedia` flag.

Answer (score 7):

> **Hiding your files from the Media**
>
> Scanner Include an empty file named
>   .nomedia in your external files
>   directory (note the dot prefix in the
>   filename). This will prevent Android's
>   media scanner from reading your media
>   files and including them in apps like
>   Gallery or Music.

In  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

You may also consider saving those files as cache files or in the internal memory. More info in that link.

Answer (score 2):

just keep the files in a folder and name the folder starting with a '.'

for example:

Pictures
Videos
.private--> will not be scanned for any media
Eboks

Answer (score 1):

Along with these solutions using picasa is an alternative too... and .nomedia or .foldername suggestions are generally useful but...

Including accepted answer none of the solutions solve album covers problem. 
A large number of android users are storing album covers inside the album folder and .dirname or .nomedia solutions are hiding all from both gallery and music player. The required functionality is hiding from gallery and showing in music player (else there is no reason for not deleting cover pics if we will not see them right? )

Here is the solution ;

```
Rename all album cover picture files to albumart.jpg
```

(or what picture you desire to hide from gallery)

This way gallery will not include them and music player will still use :)
Alternatively for any folder if you place a folder.jpg file in it that file will be ignored by gallery application.

As you can see we can only exclude max 2 files (pictures) from gallery application, not more :(

After you do this changes no need to clean caches of gallery and media scanner and reboot (still an option) just run an application that triggers scanning of media on every run. I prefer vaulty it refreshes media gallery on every run on photos,  but there are lots of apps, maybe you already have one installed , just use it no need to install an application for just this media scan deal.

Knowledge source : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35879

Answer (score 1):

While making external directory use something like this

```java
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("YourDirectoryName"),"YourFolderName");
```

Instead of

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "YourFolderName");
```

These files won't be detected by gallery for more reference check saving media files on this link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-receive

Answer (score 0):

Neither Windows nor Android allow the creation of the file .nomedia
It's seen as a file extension without a name.

Comment: Windows does, but not with the Explorer, you can use the command line.

Answer (score -1):

i tried everything but only this solution worked 100% you need to plug in your urb and format the sdcard check quick format box and press on restore defaults and then it will show everything in ur gallery just you need to move all your images again :)

Answer (score -1):

You can easily create the folder in Windows using Powershell

```
New-Item -path 'C:\Users\Google Drive\Pictures\.nomedia' -itemtype directory
```