# android: how to hide folder from appearing in the Gallery

Tags: android, gallery, hide, directory

I have an application that creates a folder in the sd-card. After that, I do several operations which may result in storing different media files, graphics in my folder. The problem is that this folder is then visible in the Gallery section which is not appropriate. How can I hide the folder or the contents of my folder from appearing in the Gallery?

Looking forward for a response
Thanks

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Put a file named `.nomedia` in the folder. This can be a zero-byte file if you want -- the name is what matters.

Comment: If I copy any file in the folder , like an image file. and then re-name it to .nomedia.. will it work??

Comment: @Farhan: sure, but it would be a lot simpler and faster to just create a zero-byte file.

Comment: Unfortunately this also stops music from scanning, so you can't hide all those album art showing up as single-image folders...

Comment: then how would i get back that  folder

Comment: @Mayur This helped me.. Quick and Easy solution..Now my folder is hidden from gallery and file manager too.. Thank you buddy

Comment: @CommonsWare hey i have done same thing but when phone restarts all the photo display in gallery how to resolve it?

Answer (score 6):

You will start the name of the folder with a period (.). Example:
.asdhsj

Answer (score 5):

Go to  My Files folder, then Pictures or create a folder and name it whatever you want. Go the newly created folder, add another folder again and name it .nomedia. Copy or move photos in the folder (not the .nomedia coz it won't show after creating it). Then you check in the gallery, and voila! Folder isn't shown!

PS: The pictures you have copied/moved can be viewed only in My Files folder, which is much safer.. ;)
PPS: This works on my samsung galaxy win.

Hope I had helped a little
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just start the folder name with period (.), it can be any name, but needs to start with period. After that the folder and it's files don't appear in gallery anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

For people who are on android version 5.1.1 some of you cant do this but what you can do is change the extention of that file, for example image.png change ".png" to something like ".txt" or something that way it doesnt show up in your gallery

Answer (score -1):

Happily album covers has a solution.

Here is the solution ;
Rename all album cover picture files to `albumart.jpg`

My detailed answer can be found here [Stop images on sd card from showing up in gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707102/stop-images-on-sd-card-from-showing-up-in-gallery/13666182#13666182)