# Android Prevent Gallery from Reading Application Images

Tags: android, image, gallery

My Application is filling the SD card with Images that are used by the app. I want to prevent the gallery from reading those Images programmaticly.. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible adding a empty `.nomedia` file to the folder that don't want to be scanned by the Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent Gallery from showing images from your app's folder, you can put a file named `.nomedia` in that folder.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6713863/450534

Comment: @Naskov: Glad to have been of help. :-)