# Hide folder with photos on sd card

Tags: android

I save pictures to my application on sd card. When I go to gallery I can see that pictures. How I can save pictures which I use in application on sd card but they must be invisible in gallery from phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include an empty file named .nomedia in your external files directory (note the dot prefix in the filename). This will prevent Android's media scanner from reading your media files and including them in apps like Gallery or Music.

Comment: could you write some more info about that. What is that .nomedia and where is that file

Answer (score 2):

While storing data add these two lines then the content will automatically be hidden and images not visible in device gallary.

```
File dstFile = new File(file.getParent(), "." + file.getName());
file.renameTo(dstFile);
```

It works great for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively put a dot in front of the folder name by renaming 
foldername to .foldername

But putting .nomedia file in folder and .foldername usage will hide all media files in a directory

A large number of android users are storing album covers inside the album folder and .dirname or .nomedia solutions are hiding all from both gallery and music player. The required functionality is hiding from gallery and showing in music player (else there is no reason for not deleting cover pics if we will not see them right? )

Here is the solution ;
Rename all album cover picture files to `albumart.jpg`

My detailed answer can be found here [Stop images on sd card from showing up in gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707102/stop-images-on-sd-card-from-showing-up-in-gallery/13666182#13666182)