# How can I stop images generated by my application from showing in the gallery?

Tags: android, sd-card

My app saves images to a subfolder of the DCIM folder on the SD-card in the phone.

I do not wish these images to be shown in the androids gallery app.

How can I achive this?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5707210/1665507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an empty file called `.nomedia` in the directory where you store the images

Answer (score 1):

To hide your image file add . to file name for example ***sdcard/DEIM/yourapp/.yourimage.jpg***
this will hide an Image.
If you want to hide one folder add . to the folder name ***sdcard/DEIM/.yourapp/image1.jpg***

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution: [Stop saving photos using Android native camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078892/stop-saving-photos-using-android-native-camera?rq=1)

The idea is to check which files are in the gallery just before taking the picture and just after it, delete that one that is new.

It's not the cleanest solution but it works.

May It will helps you!