# Android camera intent should not allow to save the image to gallery and store it in specified path

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

when i use this code ->

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
```

I am able to save the image to specified path but it is also saving to the gallery. I dont want to save the image to gallery. Please help here.

Thanks in advance for your valuable time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop images on sd card from showing up in gallery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707102/stop-images-on-sd-card-from-showing-up-in-gallery)

Comment: @Umakant Angadi did u find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Capture Image using below Intent -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

// create a file to save the image
File MyDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyDir");
if (!MyDir.exists()){
    MyDir.mkdirs()
}

File fileUri = new File(MyDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg"); 
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

// start the image capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

The gallery app scans the folders for Media contents and populates them in gallery.

If you wish not to display your captured images in gallery follow below methods-

1. Creating A .Nomedia File
2. Adding A Dot Prefix

Comment: Hi.. when i check in file manager i found same image stored in two folder
1)DCIM folder 
2)URI which i specified

Comment: @UmakantAngadi: check my edit. I have added code to capture image from camera Intent. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for ur code. Here I am facing issue
1) it is still saving that image into /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20160302_143206.jpg 
2) I am saving that image in /storage/emulated/0/sample/IMG_20160302_143158.png


The same image in 2 folder with different file names. I dont think phone is scanning folders and creating the same image with different file name.

My question is: phone by default creating the image and storing into DCIM folder(gallery). This should not happen. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @UmakantAngadi: Absolutely not. It doesn't scans and create duplicate file in DCIM. It simply displays the image from the your folder into gallery

Comment: @UmakantAngadi: Hey u can check this links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078892/stop-saving-photos-using-android-native-camera

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and implemented several workarounds similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390163/deleting-a-gallery-image-after-camera-intent-photo-taken/6600148#6600148).
I tried also to keep the file hidden adding the `.` prefix to the filname and to put a .nomedia file (see [MediaStore.MEDIA_IGNORE_FILENAME](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#MEDIA_IGNORE_FILENAME)) within the folder where I stored the images but in some cases, calling the camera app via intent as usual

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
    Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getString(R.string.file_provider_authority), file);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
} else {
    showToastMessage(getString(R.string.no_camera_activity), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

depending on the device and the camera app, this latter might store the picture also within the gallery (usually saving a file with a timestamp as the filename) even if you are providing an `Uri` associated to a file you are storing within your application private partition.

So I found that the most reliable way of doing what I needed was to [control the camera](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html) directly by your own or to adopt [cwac-cam2](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2) library provided by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145) within `YourActivity` in this way (note the commented `.updateMediaStore()` line)

```
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getString(R.string.file_provider_authority), file);
CameraActivity.IntentBuilder builder = new CameraActivity.IntentBuilder(this); // this refers to the activity instance
    Intent intent = builder
            .skipConfirm()
            .facing(Facing.BACK)
            .to(fileUri)
            //.updateMediaStore() // uncomment only if you want to update MediaStore
            .flashMode(FlashMode.AUTO)
            .build();
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
```